# How to fully close all background work of a view controller when modally presenting another one

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I have 2 view controllers, in the first one I make calculations that repeat in an endless loop.

The problem is that I want to close the method and everything related to the first method when presenting the second one. Also I am conforming to `MKMapViewDelegate` that is triggered everytime that user location changes, where I start a background thread work.

Now when presenting the other view controller, I want to get rid of this and break all the operations that were being executed.

I tried to set the delegates to nil, but when turn back to the first one the methods return and gives crash by saying

`"Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x17f9b100> was mutated while being enumerated."`

This is the function where I make calculations, the array has too many objects in it and takes about 10 sec to fully check this method.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        [self makeCalculations];
    });
}

-(void)makeCalculations {
    BOOL okClicked = NO;

    for(NSDictionary *item in array) {
        NSInteger responseCode = [[item objectForKey:@"responseCode"] integerValue];

        okClicked = (responseCode > 0);

        if (okClicked) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"title" message:@"message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
                alert.tag =10;
                [alert show];
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any clue and can you provide me an example or suggestion?

Comment: Please include some of your code, or this question is unanswerable.

Comment: please provide some of your code. If you are using the loop then you can use  'break;' inside the loop or a "if" check inside the loop which allow the loop to run until other view controller shows up.

Comment: Unrelated: What is the purpose of MakeCalc and why is it called every time user location is updated?  Why can't the code that _sets_ responseCode show the alert view?  Is it possible to have multiple items with responseCode > 0?  In that case, current code will show multiple alert views.

Comment: I dont understand why I am getting down votes. I have implemented this method in my program I just showed you the way how I call it. I have handled when showing multiple alerts, because this is just a simple way teeling my problem. There are different response code but that was not the point of my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a counter and increment it in the loop. Then use something like:

```
if(counter % 100 == 0) {
    if(self.cancelled) {
        self.cancelled = NO;
        return;
    }
}
```

Now, just set the `cancelled` `BOOL` when you present the new modal.

You don't strictly need the counter, you could just check the flag each time...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, its a good idea, but my point was to know if I can close the method in another way?

Comment: To 'close' the method you need to `return`. You can choose how to trigger it.

Comment: Thnx Wain, your first answer works perfectly! It took me some to configure it correctly!